# Cypress not waiting for Before block to complete

Tags: promise, mocha.js, bdd, cypress

I am trying to achieve the following functionality

Before Block : Call the Cy.visit("/login") and call a Function which will trigger a REST API and process the REST API response and set the local storage.

Only after the local storage is set click on "My Account" Link

Here is the source Code I am trying.

```
    import * as subscriberHelpers from '../../../helpers/subscriberHelpers';
    import * as localStorage from '../../../helpers/localStorage';


describe('testCode', () => {
    before((done) => {
        cy.visit('/login', {
            timeout: 10000,
            onLoad: () => {
                localStorage.write("CD-Environment", Cypress.env('defaultEnvironment'));
                localStorage.write("CD-Language", "en-US");
                localStorage.write("CD-SystemId", "85788485-e411-48a9-b478-610c1285dc1a");
            }
        })
        subscriberHelpers.createSubscriber().then(()=>{
            done();
        })

    })

    it('sClick on my account link', () => {
        cy.get('.c-header-listItem > .c-link').contains("My Account").click();
    })
})
```

Here is the code to createSubscriber function

```
export function createSubscriber() {

    let URL = `SOME URL`;
    let body = {
       Some Body
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.subscriberServiceRequest(URL, body).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200 && ("SessionId" in response.body)) {
                localStorage.write("CD-SessionId", response.body.SessionId);
                localStorage.write("CD-SubscriberId", response.body.Subscriber.Id);
                resolve();
            }
            else if (response.status === 200 && ("Fault" in response.body)) {
                reject(response.body.Fault.Message);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Here is the code to subscriber Service request function

```
export function subscriberServiceRequest(url, body, headers = null) {
    let defaultHeaders = { "CD-SystemId": "85788485-e411-48a9-b478-610c1285dc1a" }
    if (headers != null) {
        defaultHeaders = addHeaders(defaultHeaders, headers);
    }
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cy.request({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            body: body,
            headers: defaultHeaders
        }).then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        });
    })
}
```

When I try Executing the code I am getting following error in cypress

[image: Console Error]
[image: Cypress UI]

But the element existing in the UI

[image: Element]

Questions:

1. Why I am getting the error
2. How to call more than one async functions
   in before block
3. How to tell cypress to wait till the functions on
   before block get processed meaning not only wait till receiving the
   response but wait till the response got processed in the THEN block

Comment: `cy.get('.c-header-listItem > .c-link').contains("My Account").click();` looks fine to me.

Comment: I think a clue is in the message **Because this error occurred during a 'before all' hook...**, but clearly you do not intend the `cy.get...` to be in the `before()`. I cannot see any reason why (e.g missing closing bracket). I think the problem is in the use of `done()` - there seems to be no Cypress example using done(), and it does not play well when I add it to my own test.

Comment: I suggest you try `cy.route('SOME URL').as('getPostResponse'); cy.visit(...); cy.wait('@getPostResponse');` See [route command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Without-Stubbing).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

> Why I am getting the error

`.contains()` specifically searches for elements within but not including the tag it is called on. In other words, `someElement.contains("My Account")` will not match `someElement`.

What you should have instead is this:

```
cy.get('.c-header-listItem').contains("My Account").click();
```

Or simply:

```
cy.contains("My Account").click();
```